# Using DataTables' range filter with language.decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been trying to try range filter using datatables.net's datatable. 
But my price column price ranges from millions to millions. Therefore, it will need to have commas to separates one, tenth, hundreds, thousands.. and so on.

I've seen Datatable's language.decimal. But it doesn't seems to work at all.

Here's my declaration of my DataTable();

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "language": {
        "decimal": "-",
        "thousands": "."
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only need to convert the strings that exist for your large values into numbers by stripping out the non-numeric values. Building off of the [range filter example](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) on dataTables, I've done it here using a regex on the value read in. I did it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t13zLLLc/1/) for some typical test data that uses column 5 for salary, but you should be able to modify this accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
} );

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
        var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );

        // MODIFY THE COLUMN FOR VALUE:
        var value = parseFloat( data[5].replace(/\D/g,'') ) || 0;

        if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( isNaN( min ) && value <= max ) ||
             ( min <= value   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
             ( min <= value   && value <= max ) )
        {
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```